# Redirecting in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

I've made a CMS, in Laravel, for a local charity, as part of my final research project. I have to present it in the morning and I have one niggling problem, that I can't figure out.

I have posts and comments, users and admins. Any authenticated user-type can comment on a post. I have a modal, for logging in, on the single post page and this is just a simple @if statement, that replaces the button.

If I login as an admin, I'm redirected to the admin panel, which is what I wanted. If I login as a user, i'm redirected to home; not good. I simply want to redirect a user using return back()->withInput I cannot seem to find the right class that deals with a user's redirect. I have tried in the login controller and the redirectIfAuthenticated middleware and neither works.

I'm tired, it's 4am and I'm probably looking in the wrong files. A little help would be great though, thank you.

Comment: have you tried getting the `UrlGenerator` of the back() object to see if that will do what you want?

Comment: I manged to fix it, just now. It turns out I can't use the helper method, in the redirectTo() function. So I had to request the url with: return url()->previous(); that at least takes the user back to where they were. It obviously doesn't save the old input, but I can disable the input box, for now.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest solution is to define an `authenticated` method inside your `AuthController` and put the logic there:

```
   protected function authenticated($request, $user)
    {
        if($user->role === 'admin') {
            return redirect()->intended('/admin_path_here');
        }

        return redirect()->intended('/path_for_normal_user');
    }
```